# PHP: Предупреждение Couldn't fetch mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
function query($query) {
    return $this->mysqli->query($query);
}

function select(){

    // ...

    while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }

    $result_set->close();
    return $data;
}
```

- В других вопросах Stackoverflow, котоыре я прочитал, причиной подобного предупреждения были функции `$result_set->close();` или `mysqli_free_result($articles_data);`, вызванные внутри блока `while`, но у меня, как видите, не так.
- С помощью отладчика я установил, что данное предупреждение возникает при выполнении строки `$result_set->close();`, то есть цикл благополучно завершается, кроме того, в массиве находятся правильные данные (в смысле то, которые я хотел получить из БД).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- `$result_set` перез вызовом `fetch_assoc`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Сообщение выведено как Warning, т. е. после него программа продолжает выполняться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Обновление** Полный листинг функций

```
private function query($query) {
    return $this->mysqli->query($query);
}

private function query($query) {
    return $this->mysqli->query($query);
}

private function select($table_name, $fields, $where = "", $order = "", $up = true, $limit = "") {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($fields); $i++) {
        if ((strpos($fields[$i], "(") === false) && ($fields[$i] != "*")) {
            $fields[$i] = "`".$fields[$i]."`";
        }
    }

    $fields = implode(",", $fields);
    $table_name = $this->config->adminPanel_TablePrefix.$table_name;

    if (!$order) {
        $order = "ORDER BY `id`";
    }
    else {
        if ($order != "RAND()") {
                $order = "ORDER BY `$order`";
                if (!$up) {
                    $order .= " DESC";
                }
        }
        else {
            $order = "ORDER BY $order";
        }
    }

    if ($limit) {
        $limit = "LIMIT $limit";
    }

    if ($where) {
        $query = "SELECT $fields FROM $table_name WHERE $where $order $limit";
    }
    else {
        $query = "SELECT $fields FROM $table_name $order $limit";
    }

    $result_set = $this->query($query);

    if (!$result_set) {
        return false;
    }
    $i = 0;

    while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }

    $result_set->close();
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: А как у вас $result_set получается ? и еще сам $query показать.

Comment: Да не вопрос, только функция длинная.

Comment: Что-то порывшись интернете и в доках у меня возникло вопросов больше чем ответов. Первое что мне непонятно, почему у $result_set в [доках](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.mysqli-result.php) нету метода `close`. Во вторых, в тех же [доках](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php#103422) пишут почему такая ошибка может возникать. В общем говорят о том, что у вас соединение к моменту вызова `close` закрыто. А можете целиком класс сюда выкинуть и места где вы вызываете метод `select` ?

Comment: Благодарю Вас за время, потраченное на поиск причины. Поскольку кода довольно много, то я загрузил нужные файлы на [Яндекс Диск](https://yadi.sk/d/fLeX_0G837tap8).

Comment: Я запустил ваш код. Все работает, варнингов нет. Единственное предположение у меня осталось по поводу самих запросов в mysql. В функции `select` перед `$result_set = $this->query($query);` сделайте вывод `echo $query . "\n";` посмотреть

Comment: Ещё раз благодарю Вас за потраченное время. Не могли бы Вы оформить Ваши изыскания в виде ответа, чтобы я смог поставить Вам галочку?